# TableLayoutPanel trying to be a button

Tags: c#, windows, button, tablelayout, tablelayoutpanel

Language: C#
.Net Framework 4.7.2
I use WinForms
The code runs from the constructor, when I use the Event shown, the same thing happens.

So, this is my code:

```
        foreach (Button btn in this.tlpColorSettings.Controls)
        {
            btn.ForeColor = Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonColor;
            btn.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.TextColor;
        }
```

Everytime I run it, it says that it can't convert a TableLayoutPanel to a Button. Why does it try to convert it? It should only run when it detects a button.
I have 2 buttons in my TableLayoutPanel.

When I use this.controls (view) the same happens.

Comment: `foreach (var btn in this.tlpColorSettings.Controls.OfType<Button>()) { ... }`

Comment: If you get that error, then you definitely have a TableLayoutPanel in your tlpColorSettings and not only two buttons. Check your designer, showing the Document Layout window could help.